# How to save settings in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, debugging

Does anyone know how to save gdb settings (like "set print pretty on" or "set print elements 0", both from [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html))? I don't want to set my configuration every time that I will use gdb :/

I searched in google and SO, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Add any commands you want to auto run in the *.gdbinit* file in your home directory.

Comment: For the record, this also works for the gdb inside Xcode. I added `handle SIGPIPE nostop` to `.gdbinit` to fix [this problem](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/Jul/msg00088.html).

Comment: Dear I like to add command to let my cross arm gdb starts the target gdb(on raspberry) automatically, how may I set the gdbinit file? please help bro, commands?

Comment: **TIP:** adding  `add-auto-load-safe-path <path>` in `~/.gdbinit` allows to add additional `gdbinit`s, so you can have one per project for example!

Comment: Or even add `set-auto-load safe-path /` to `.gdbinit`, if you don't want to add every project separately and security is not a concern.

Answer (score 6):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2045532/11722) works for commands that can run before the binary is loaded, but for example if you want to add `catch throw` you cannot do it in *.gdbinit* since that command needs to run after the binary is loaded.

But gdb can take a file with commands to run after binary loading using:

```
-x file
       Execute GDB commands from file file.
```

I automated that by creating an alias:

```
alias gdb='gdb -x ~/.gdbinit_x'
```

and added my after binary load commands in that file.

Comment: Nice addition to the answer. Thanks!