# How to set GDB debugging print options at once?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I use GDB very often to debug my C-program and I use the print options like :

1. set print pretty on
2. set print array-index on

But at moment I need to set these print options everytime I open a new GDB session. 
I am looking for a way such that I can set these print options once forever so that print options are set in every new GDB session.

thanks

Comment: Give a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045509/how-to-save-settings-in-gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a `gdbinit` file on your home directory.

```
 ~/.gdbinit
```

See: [gdbinit manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-gdbinit/)

From the manpage:

> These files contain GDB commands to automatically execute during GDB startup